# Java Servlet catch all web requests then call JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I am in the following situation:

Client makes some request -> Servlet gets all requests -> based on requested url (example: https://bla.com/classic) it fetches products from database -> invokes a jsp page and passes products array as parameter -> jsp page rendes HTML to client

How can this be achieved ?
More specific question:

1.How to catch all client requests with a servlet and get the requested url ?

2.How to call jsp from servlet and pass parameters to it, so it can render the correct HTML ?

I am trying to build an MVC-like application. In this case my servlet is the controller (gets all requests), a database-helper-class is my model (gets products from db) and the jsp file is my view (renders html).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need something called as a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ServletFilter and a properly configured web.xml for the paths.

Comment: An example would be [Example servlet filter that catches and blocks ips that request suspicious url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394628/example-servlet-filter-that-catches-and-blocks-ips-that-request-suspicious-url)

Comment: I tried with this annotation for my Servlet and its doing the job: @WebServlet("/*")
public class ServletT extends HttpServlet {..}

Comment: that's an actual servlet. which will work, too. but typically people use servlet filters for such things. but what you did works, obviously.